# why i Can't access array of objects which i have created in switch case

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  class StudentDetails
  {
    int regno,no_of_arrears;
    String name;
    float cgpa;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    StudentDetails()
    {
        regno=0;
        no_of_arrears=0;
        name="";
        cgpa=0.0F;
    }   
    void setStudentDetails()
    {
        System.out.print("\nEnter Student regno : ");
        regno=in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nEnter Student name : ");
        name=in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nEnter Student CGPA : ");
        cgpa=in.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("\nEnter Student no.of.arrears : ");
        no_of_arrears=in.nextInt(); 
    }
    void printStudentDetails()
    {
        System.out.println(regno+"\t"+name+"\t"+cgpa);  
    }
    boolean isPlacementEligible()
    {
        if(cgpa >= 7.5 && no_of_arrears==0)
        {   
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

  }
  class Student
  { 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n=0,i,count=0,ch;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\t\t\tSTUDENT LIST");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t------------");
        System.out.println("1.Set Student Details\n2.Print all Students\n3.Print   Placement Eligible Student\n4.Exit");    
        do{
            System.out.print("\nEnter the choice : ");
            ch=in.nextInt();
            StudentDetails s1=new StudentDetails();
            StudentDetails s[]={s1};
            switch(ch){
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("\nEnter no of students : ");
                    n=in.nextInt();
                    s=new StudentDetails[n];
                    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {   
                        s[i]=new StudentDetails();
                        System.out.print("\nEnter Details Of Student "+(i+1));
                        System.out.println("\n--------------------------");
                        s[i].setStudentDetails();
                        if(s[i].isPlacementEligible())
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(n);
                    System.out.println("\nDetails of All Students ");
                    System.out.println("\n------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Total no of students : "+n);
                    System.out.println("Regno\tName\tCGPA");
                    System.out.println("-----\t----\t----");
                    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                        s[i].printStudentDetails();

                    }   
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\nDetails of Eligible Students ");
                    System.out.println("\n-----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Eligible for placements : "+count);
                    System.out.println("Regno\tName\tCGPA");
                    System.out.println("-----\t----\t----");
                    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                        if(s[i].isPlacementEligible())
                        {
                            s[i].printStudentDetails();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("Enter correct choice ");
            }   
        }while(ch!=4);
    }   
}
```

Output :
    STUDENT LIST
            ------------
1.Set Student Details
2.Print all Students
3.Print Placement Eligible Student
4.Exit

Enter the choice : 1

Enter no of students : 1

### Enter Details Of Student 1

Enter Student regno : 1

Enter Student name : sjnsj

Enter Student CGPA : 9.8

Enter Student no.of.arrears : 0

Enter the choice : 2
1

Details of All Students

---

Total no of students : 1

Regno   Name    CGPA
-----   ----    ----
0       0.0

Enter the choice : 4

Here i have created array of objects in case1 and it couldn't read in case 2

Answer (score 0):

You declare your array inside your do-while loop, so it goes out of scope every iteration of the loop.

Even if you instantiated it on a previous iteration of the loop in `case1`, you will still be accessing a completely different array in every other iteration of the loop.

If you want to use the same array for each iteration, declare it outside of your loop

```
StudentDetails s1=new StudentDetails();
StudentDetails s[]={s1};
do
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have declared `s` variable inside loop body. Change your code like that:

```
    ...
    System.out.println("1.Set Student Details\n2.Print all Students\n3.Print   Placement Eligible Student\n4.Exit");  
    StudentDetails s[]= null;  
    do{
        System.out.print("\nEnter the choice : ");
        ch=in.nextInt();
        StudentDetails s1=new StudentDetails();
        s[]={s1};
        switch(ch){
     ....
```